# Complete Forced Oscillation (with Fourier Transform)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, physics

This equation comes from Physics but here I need your mathematical skills to verify it 2 ways:

First of consider the holy Differential equation of forced oscillation: $$\boxed{m\,\ddot{x}+\beta\,\dot{x}+m\,{\omega_0}^2\,x = F_A\,\cos(\omega_t\,t)}$$

It's an equation that describes a fundamental equilibrium of forces.

The mathematical solution already has been provided here, but in my eyes incomplete.

Here I want to write out the complete solution of that ODE for $x(t)$.

### $\color{gray}{\textbf{First Method}}$

$\textbf{Homogenous Part:}$

$\textsf{setting} \quad$ $m\,\ddot{x}+\beta\,\dot{x}+m\,{\omega_0}^2\,x = 0$  $\quad \textsf{and using an exponential ansatz yields:}$

$\underline{\text{Homogenous Part:}} \quad$

$$\boxed{x_h(t) = 
C_1\,e^{\textstyle-\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\,t}\,e^{\textstyle{i\sqrt{{w_0}^2-\left(\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\right)^2}}\,t}+
C_2\,e^{\textstyle-\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\,t}\,e^{\textstyle{-i\sqrt{{w_0}^2-\left(\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\right)^2}}\,t}}$$

Provided that

$\bullet \quad$$C_1$ and $C_1$ are real constants $c_1$ and $c_2$
$\bullet\quad{\omega_0}^2 > \left(\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\right)^2$
$\bullet \quad \omega_e= \sqrt{{\omega_0}^2-\left(\frac{\beta}{2\,m}\right)^2}$
$\bullet\quad \frac{\beta}{2\,m} = \gamma$

$\textsf{this can be rewritten:}$

$$\boxed{x_h(t) = e^{\textstyle -\gamma\,t}\,\left[c_1\cos(\omega_e\,t)+c_2\sin(\omega_e\,t)\right]}$$

Actually there exist starting conditions like $x(0) = A_0$, $\dot{x}(0) = 0$, but we can spare that.

$\textbf{Inhomogeneous Part}:$

$\textsf{looking at $\quad m\,\ddot{x}+\beta\,\dot{x}+m\,{\omega_0}^2\,x = F_A\,\cos(\omega_t\,t)\quad$ using the ansatz $x_p(t) = a\,e^{\textstyle i\varphi}\,e^{\textstyle i\,\omega_t\,t}$ brings:}$

$\underline{\text{Inhomogeneous Part:}}$

$$\boxed{x_p(t) = \frac{F_A}{\sqrt{m^2\,\left(w_0^2-{w_t}^2\right)^2+(\beta\,\omega_t)^2}}\,\cos\left(\omega_t\,t-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta\,\omega_t}{m\,\left({\omega_0}^2-\omega_t\right)}\right)\right)}$$

$\textbf{Total Solution:}$

The complete solution is given by $x(t) = x_h(t)+x_p(t)$. I won't write that out additionally. It's there.

Note that $\omega_t$ is a fixed excitation frequency for all times $t$. The Only changing variable is $t$ itself

I just mentioned all of that because I didn't see it appearing here but it is building to my question.

> $\textbf{Question 1:}$

First of, what's the shape of the function? This might be physical, but just looking at the solution:

Is it really a decaying wave going over to a stabilised wave?

### $\color{gray}{\textbf{Second Method}}$

$\textbf{Fourier Transform:}$

$\textsf{Transforming $\quad m\,\ddot{x}+\beta\,\dot{x}+m\,{\omega_0}^2\,x = F_A\,\cos(\omega_t\,t)\quad$ to frequency domain gives:}$

$\underline{\text{Fourier Transform:}}$

$$\begin{align}\left(-m\,\omega^2-i\,\omega\,\beta+m\,{\omega_0}^2\right)\,X(\omega) = \\\\
F_A\,\pi\,[\delta(\omega-\omega_t)+\delta(\omega+\omega_t)]\end{align}$$

$\textsf{so after rearranging:}$

$$X(\omega) = \dfrac{F_A\,\pi\,[\delta(\omega-\omega_t)+\delta(\omega+\omega_t)]}{\left(-m\,\omega^2-i\,\omega\,\beta+m\,{\omega_0}^2\right)}$$

Here I'm totally not sure if this is the right one. It's for sure, $x(\omega)$ depends no longer on $t$, but $\omega$

There I ask myself $\cdots$

> $\textbf{Question 2}$

Where the frequency $\omega$ belongs to? Is it from the oscillation source? I assumed that's fixed.

> $\textbf{Question 3}$

Does the Inverse FT bring back the full solution derived for $x(t)$? I know I had to solve:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{F_A\,\pi\,[\delta(\omega-\omega_t)+\delta(\omega+\omega_t)]}{\left(-m\,\omega^2-i\,\beta+m\,{\omega_0}^2\right)}\right)\,e^{\textstyle i\,\omega\,t}\,\mathrm{d\omega}$$

$\textbf{Conclusion:}$

At this point I lack the experience to solve for $x(t)$. On top I haven't seen the complete solution.

Consequently I beg you to bring this to an end with me.

Comment: In the first approach computing the particular solution, what is $ω$? It should be $ω_t$ from the start, else you do not get equality with the forcing term.

Comment: Right. I thought the frequency in $e^{\textstyle i\,\omega\,t}$ is a different one but it happens to be fixed $\omega_t$. The main question remains: why the FT assumes a variable frequency $\omega$ (Where does it belong to) and how the solutions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions to the two parts give the shape of the solution.  As long as $\beta$ is small the homogeneous part is a decaying sine wave at a slightly lower frequency than the frequency with no resistance.  When $\beta$ is too large $\omega_e$ becomes imaginary, the oscillation disappears, and the system slowly approaches equilibrium.  This part depends on the initial conditions.  The inhomogeneous part is a sine wave at the driving frequency.  It does not depend on the initial conditions and will persist as long as the driving term continues.

$x(\omega)$ (it would be better to use a different variable, maybe call it $X(\omega)$) is the Fourier transform of the position.  $\omega$ ranges over all frequencies, positive and negative.  You get back to $x_p(t)$ by doing an inverse Fourier transform.  Your expression only has the effect of the driven oscillation in it.

Comment: How do I include the damping/decaying part $x_h(t)$? Also I don‘t see a way of getting back the phase $\arctan(\cdots)$ by performing the Inverse FT. As I said, I don‘t even know how to arrive there. It‘s just unimaginable to me the solutions are equalized.

Comment: If you have nonzero initial conditions they should show up in the Fourier transform.  Your Fourier transform is basically replacing $\frac d{dt}$ by $i\omega$, which works if things are continuous.  You need to incorporate step functions in the position and velocity at $t=0$ in the transform.  I forget how to do that.